# Geometry shader: Dynamic output?

Tags: directx11, hlsl, sharpdx, geometry-shader

I'm currently using a geometry shader to generate grass blades out of single root points that are layed out in a grid. For each root point, I generate a grass blade with, right now, a constant number of vertices.

However, for level of detail, I would like to generate a number of vertices depending on the distance to the camera. Now, since there are no dynamic arrays, I tried to declare multiple techniques which call the geometry shader with the number of vertices.

I would then be able to divide my grass into patches/smaller grids, calculate the distance to the camera for this patch and then call the technique with the appropriate number of vertices.

The HLSL part looks something like this:

```
[maxvertexcount(24)]
void GS_LOD1(point GEO_IN points[1], inout TriangleStream<GEO_OUT> output) 
{
    GS_Shader(points, 8, output);
}

[maxvertexcount(24)]
void GS_LOD2(point GEO_IN points[1], inout TriangleStream<GEO_OUT> output)
{
    GS_Shader(points, 16, output);
}

technique LevelOfDetail1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 VS_Shader();
        GeometryShader = compile gs_4_0 GS_LOD1();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 PS_Shader();
    }
}

technique LevelOfDetail2
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 VS_Shader();
        GeometryShader = compile gs_4_0 GS_LOD2();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 PS_Shader();
    }
}
```

And the definition of the GS function:

```
void GS_Shader(point GEO_IN points[1], in const int realVertexCount, inout TriangleStream<GEO_OUT> output) 
{
  [...]
  GEO_OUT v[realVertexCount];
```

However, even this way the compiler complains:

> array dimensions must be literal scalar expressions

Is this possible in any way? I guess what would is just writing several geometry shaders that basically do the same thing but with a already defined number of vertices - this sounds a bit messy though.

Thanks!

Comment: in  openGL you can stop emitting primitives in the geom shader even when the amount of vertices is below the number specified in the output

Comment: Thanks! I tried this yesterday and didn't have any success because of another error - this is actually working now. Now I just need to check if it makes more sense to calculate the LOD for patches on the CPU or for each primitive in the geometry shader, guess I will try.